# Get Android Studio Project from APK file

Tags: java, android-studio, dex2jar

I have an APK file on my phone for an app that I was testing. I, not realizing that I didn't back up my source Android Studio project, deleted the source as I was looking for an older version online. Regardless to say, I didn't find the older source, or the version I wanted and am wondering if it is possible in any way to get the APK in an Android Studio Project manner. I've tried using dex2jar and other tools, but they do not make it openable and exportable by Android Studio. Is there a step I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel your pain. There are some [tools](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) for reverse engineering apk's but don't expect the results to be identical.

I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: Thank you! I've never personally heard of apktool and ill try it as I get home! This is a lifesavw

Comment: I''ve used it succesfully before. But I will give you the same disclaimer, _**the reverse engineered product might not be the same. You will still have to make some changes!**_

Comment: Yes. At least it's better than starting from scratch. I'm fine with making changes as it is better than restarting